# How to count unique combinations of values in selected columns in pandas data frame including frequencies with the value of 0?

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe (assume it is called df), I have two columns: one labeled colour and one labeled TOY_ID. Using `df.groupby(['Colour', 'TOY_ID']).size()` I was able to generate a third column which is unnamed that represents the frequency of the number of times that the other two columns' values have appeared in my df. The output example is shown below:

```
Colour            TOY_ID
Blue              31490.0       50
                  31569.0       50
                  50360636.0    20

                                ..
Yellow            50360636.0    25
                  50366678.0     9

                                ..
Green             31490.0       17
                  50366678.0    10
```

Although this method is working, it does not show the combinations where the first two columns have values of 0. I know this can be done in R but I am unsure how can I do this in Python. The example of my desired output is below. Any suggestions?

```
Colour            TOY_ID
Blue                 31490.0    50
                     31569.0    50
                  50360636.0    20
                  50366678.0     0
                                ..
Yellow               31490.0     0
                     31569.0     0
                  50360636.0    25
                  50366678.0     9
                                ..
Green                31490.0    17
                     31569.0     0
                  50360636.0     0
                  50366678.0    10
```

Comment: You want a TOY_ID thats currently only present in combination with colour Yellow also occure unter Blue/Green but then with 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['Colour', 'TOY_ID']).size()


s = s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels), fill_value=0)
print (s)
Colour  TOY_ID    
Blue    31490.0       50
        31569.0       50
        50360636.0    20
        50366678.0     0
Green   31490.0       17
        31569.0        0
        50360636.0     0
        50366678.0    10
Yellow  31490.0        0
        31569.0        0
        50360636.0    25
        50366678.0     9
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: it gives me the error 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'levels'

Comment: @YOLOLJJ - It seems there is some `reset_index`, how working `s = df.groupby(['Colour', 'TOY_ID']).size()` ?